# sigsuspend() in 3 forks

Tags: c, signals, fork, handler

I'm running a program with 3 forks: 
(read /dev/urandom ---pipe--> some funny stuff ---fifo--> stdout). 
I need to write a sighandler to stop and start (any number of times) all these forks. I've written this...

```
    static int pid_table[3];
    struct sigaction act;
    sigset_t set1;

    static void hdl (int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{
   switch(sig)
   {
     int i;

      case SIGUSR1:
        sigsuspend(&set1);
        break;
      break;

      case SIGINT:

       for(i = 0; i<=2; i++) kill(pid_table[i], SIGUSR1);
       break;

      case SIGUSR2:
        for(i = 2; i>=0; i--)  kill(pid_table[i], SIGCONT);
      break;

      case SIGCONT:

      break;
   }
}
```

I send signals from another terminal. 
When i type SIGINT, it sends SIGUSR1 to all 3 proccesses. SIGUSR1 `sigsuspend()` all of them. The set1 is empty set of signals.

When I type SIGUSR2 the handler should send SIGCONT (don't know why this one, but i think its ok) to all of these 3 proccesses. Handler for SIGCONT is just empty (to make `sigsuspend()` return).

And there is the problem. When I type SIGUSR2, the programm doesn't start... I need to send 2 SIGUSR2 signals to start the programme again. Anybody know how to avoid this 2nd sending ? (Sry for low english)

Comment: As you see I tried to kill() SIGCONT twice... But it didin't work

Comment: "*`SIGUSR1` `sigsuspend()` all of them*" are you sure? As it stands it suspends the calling process.

Comment: Also the code you show is much to incomplete to understand what all might go wrong.

Comment: Yeah. Checked that. I copied old version... I think its simple... I want to send one signal which will "tripple" to each of my 3 fork() proccesses...

Comment: Loops are for "branching" the signal i send from another terminal.